# Oracle regexp_substr to extract data - 2

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

Old question id = 62489141

I have added another input text.

I am trying to extract download and upload speed number from the string, not able to achieve it, please help.

Below string exists in one of column of table

Input String:

```
My ADSL 2M(200) Volume 14Mbps/2M speed threshold 0M
```

I need out of SQL should be

```
download_speed upload_spped
14             2
```

Previous suggested SQLs extracting data correctly provided if there is no other numbers.

Comment: What you need to do is identify the pattern for the strings. For this one string there are many possibilities (download speed starting at character position 24 or starting after 'Volume ' or being the third integer and being two digits long or being followed by 'Mbps', etc.). But what does account for other strings, too? Do they all start with `My ADSL 2M(200) Volume` for instance? Tell us what is fixed and what is variable in the strings you are dealing with.

Comment: I assume the units are fixed? Otherwise you would show 2 for 2K, 2M, and 2G.

Answer (score 0):

Read comments within code.

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    -- sample data
  3    (select 'My ADSL 2M(200) Volume 14Mbps/2M speed threshold 0M' from dual),
  4  spaces as
  5    -- find positions of all spaces within the sample string
  6    (select instr(col, ' ', 1, level) space_position
  7     from test
  8     connect by level <= regexp_count(col, ' ')
  9    ),
 10  speed as
 11    -- find position of the " speed" string
 12    (select col,
 13            instr(col, ' speed') speed_position
 14     from test
 15    ),
 16  downup as
 17    -- extract the whole "donwload/upload" string
 18    (select trim(substr(col, s.space_position, p.speed_position - s.space_position)) val
 19     from speed p cross join spaces s
 20     where s.space_position = (select max(s1.space_position)
 21                               from spaces s1
 22                               where s1.space_position < p.speed_position
 23                             )
 24    )
 25  -- final result
 26  select regexp_substr(val, '\d+', 1, 1) download_speed,
 27         regexp_substr(val, '\d+', 1, 2) upload_speed
 28  from downup;

DOWNLOAD_SPEED  UPLOAD_SPEED
--------------- ---------------
14              2

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REGEXP_REPLACE()` function including patterns, one of which is starting from the string `Volume`, and the other from the slash(`/`) which's assumed to be unique within each of your string values :

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(str,'(.*Volume )(\d+)(.*)','\2') AS download_speed, 
       REGEXP_REPLACE(str,'(.*\/)(\d+)(.*)','\2') AS upload_speed
  FROM tab
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=61850a3043e11bb99990954b4ce5b5af)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_substr` as follows:

```
with d (str) as
(select 'My ADSL 2M(200) Volume 14Mbps/2M speed threshold 0M'
 from dual)
 -- your query starts from here.
select regexp_substr(spd, '[0-9]+',1,1) as download_speed,
regexp_substr(spd, '[0-9]+',1,2) as upload_speed
from
 (select regexp_substr(str, '[0-9]+M[a-z|A-Z]+/[0-9]+[a-z|A-Z]+') as spd
    from d)
```